# Save img to text result and check if duplicate one by one

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm doing python OCR image to text, and compare if there is duplicate, I'm checking one by one so that I can locate easier

> ex: listA = [1, 2 ,3 , 4, 4, 5, 6]
> so when I append list A, can show 4 is duplicate

**Mian issue: `my list "listOfElems" is empty` and `want to save text and detect is duplicate in list one by one`**

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import cv2 
import numpy as np
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

mypath = "/home/DC_ton/desktop/test_11_8/output02"
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
print(onlyfiles)

i = 1
listOfElems = []
Number_of_onlyfiles = len(onlyfiles)
while i < Number_of_onlyfiles :
    each_file_path = '/home/DC_ton/desktop/test_11_8/output02/'+ onlyfiles[i]
    image = Image.open(each_file_path)
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng')
    print(text)
       
    
    for text in listOfElems:
        if text not in listOfElems:
            listOfElems.append(text)
        else:
            print("here get duplicate")
     
    i +=1
    
print(listOfElems)  

newlist = [] 
duplist = []

def checkIfDuplicates_1(listOfElems):
    ''' Check if given list contains any duplicates '''
    if len(listOfElems) == len(set(listOfElems)):
        return False
    else:
        return True
    
result = checkIfDuplicates_1(listOfElems)
if result:
    print('Yes, list contains duplicates')
else:
    print('No duplicates found in list')  


for k in listOfElems:
    if k not in newlist:
        newlist.append(k)
    else:
        duplist.append(k) 
print("List of duplicates", duplist)
```

- output: `my list "listOfElems" is empty` and I want to compare one by one

```
['final_output_11.png', 'final_output_6.png', 'final_output_17.png', 'final_output_8.png', 'final_output_15.png', 'final_output_14.png', 'final_output_2.png', 'final_output_12.png', 'final_output_21.png', 'final_output_3.png', 'final_output_24.png', 'final_output_18.png', 'final_output_19.png', 'final_output_10.png', 'final_output_29.png', 'final_output_9.png', 'final_output_20.png', 'final_output_7.png', 'final_output_31.png', 'final_output_30.png', 'final_output_25.png', 'final_output_1.png', 'final_output_16.png', 'final_output_5.png', 'final_output_27.png', 'final_output_13.png', 'final_output_28.png', 'final_output_4.png', 'final_output_23.png', 'final_output_26.png', 'final_output_22.png']
CA7T4B2


CAT7T4BF


CAT4B8


CAT4BE


CAT4C4







CAT4C1


CAT4B7


CA7T4CB


 


CAT4cs


CAT4B4


CAT4BA


CAT7T4BC


CA74B9


CAT4BD


(CAT4AF


CAT4CA


[]
No duplicates found in list
List of duplicates []
```

image link: that I can check "entire set" if duplicate, just don't know for one by one
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQh5G.jpg

and I searched the discution said the similar case, but I failed for fitting to my case, therefore, I still need a hand [How to get Array one by one Randomly in array order in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69662143/how-to-get-array-one-by-one-randomly-in-array-order-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating an empty list, never add anything to it and then iterate over it (nothing)

```
i = 1
listOfElems = [] # <- empty
Number_of_onlyfiles = len(onlyfiles)
while i < Number_of_onlyfiles :
    each_file_path = '/home/DC_ton/desktop/test_11_8/output02/'+ onlyfiles[i]
    image = Image.open(each_file_path)
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng')
    print(text)
   

    for text in listOfElems: # <- still empty
        if text not in listOfElems:
            listOfElems.append(text)
        else:
            print("here get duplicate")
 
    i +=1
```

Easy solution would be to add the current element to the list if it isn't in there already. Like so:

```
while i < Number_of_onlyfiles :
    each_file_path = '/home/DC_ton/desktop/test_11_8/output02/'+ onlyfiles[i]
    image = Image.open(each_file_path)
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng')
    print(text)
    if text not in listOfElems:
        listOfElems.append(text)
    else:
        print("Duplicate")
```

Also note that indexes start at 0, so `i` should be `0` in the beginning
and you don't have to iterate over lists to check if an element is in it, just use the [`in`](https://www.askpython.com/python/examples/in-and-not-in-operators-in-python)operator.

You could also save a couple of lines by iterating over `onlyfiles`:

```
for file in onlyfiles:
    file_path = mypath + file
```